# Animation on GridView gets messed up on scrolling

Tags: android, gridview

What I'm trying to do is to make a `View` *shake* when clicked and stop shaking when clicked again, and I did it, but when I scroll the GridView everything gets messed up, and the shake animation on another `View` that wasn't clicked.

Here is a more clear explanation: http://i.imgur.com/IDv7vJ6.gif

I don't know why these others views are shaking.

Here is my code:

```
public class PeopleFragmentGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private Map<Integer, Boolean> animating;
private Map<Integer, ObjectAnimator> animators;

public PeopleFragmentGridAdapter(Context context, List<Person> people) {
    this.context = context;
    this.people.addAll(people);
    this.animating = new HashMap<>();
    this.animators = new HashMap<>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return people.size();
}

@Override
public Person getItem(int position) {
    return people.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder ViewHolder;
    final Person p = people.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_people_grid_peoples_item, null);
        ViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        ViewHolder.peopleGridItem = (PeopleGridItem) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_people_grid_peoples_item_item);
        convertView.setTag(ViewHolder);
    } else {
        ViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            p.setSelected(!p.isSelected());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    if (animators.get(p.getId()) == null)
        animators.put(p.getId(), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(convertView, "rotation", 0, -2, 0, 2, 0));
    if (animating.get(p.getId()) == null)
        animating.put(p.getId(), false);

    if (p.isSelected()) {
        if (!animating.get(p.getId())) {
            animating.put(p.getId(), true);
            animators.get(p.getId()).setTarget(convertView);
            animators.get(p.getId()).setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            animators.get(p.getId()).setDuration(300);
            animators.get(p.getId()).start();
        }
    } else {
        animators.get(p.getId()).setTarget(convertView);
        animating.put(p.getId(), false);
        animators.get(p.getId()).end();
        animators.get(p.getId()).cancel();
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: I edited my answer.  I realized that what I said at first, while being the root of the problem, was not the whole story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the other views are shaking is the way that Android implements GridView.  To preserve memory, it recycles views so that only those that are showing on the screen (or are about to be shown) are held in memory.  Any view that is recycled is put into a pool of unused views that can be reused in the future.  This is where the parameter "convertView" gets its views.

This means it's your job to hold onto the state of the object while it's off-screen.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
        .inflate(R.layout.fragment_people_grid_peoples_item, null);
    ViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    ViewHolder.peopleGridItem = (PeopleGridItem) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_people_grid_peoples_item_item);
    convertView.setTag(ViewHolder);
} else {
    ViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

Entering the else statement--where convertView != null--indicates that you received a recycled view, rather than inflating a new one.  It is here that you should prevent the recycled view from continuing to shake.

**Edit:** I looked more closely at your code, and I think that you are actually taking into account what I mentioned before (however not succeeding), but I'm going to leave it incase it helps someone else.  In your case, I believe the problem is that you are failing to stop your ObjectAnimator.

```
if (animators.get(p.getId()) == null)
    animators.put(p.getId(), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(convertView, "rotation", 0, -2, 0, 2, 0));
```

Here if the animator for the current Person is null. You create a new one.  Let's say that you clicked person1. ObjectAnimator1 starts animating person1. You scroll down and this view is reused for person13.  ObjectAnimator13 is created and then told to end and cancel.  ObjectAnimator1 is still active animating the view that was reused regardless of what ObjectAnimator13 says.

To remedy this you probably need to store the current id of the Person in the ViewHolder so that the first thing you can do is end any previous existing animations.  Possibly a better approach would be to store the ObjectAnimator in the ViewHolder and then not need to search it in the HashMap.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your answer it looks good. I'll try it today.

Comment: It works! Thank you again, your answer was very useful. The problem was that `BaseAdapter` recycles `convertView` on every `getView` as you and @Ashton Engberg said.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with tags much more easily than using hashmaps... In each getView call, verify if the person is selected--if not, cancel the animation. And because convertviews are recycled, you must reset their state **every** getView call (start animations where needed, cancel where not).

```
public void getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  // inflate convertviews if necessary

  Person person = people.get(position);

  ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator) convertView.getTag(R.id.tag_row_animation);
  if (person.isSelected()) {
    if (anim == null) {
      anim = getAnimator(convertView);
      anim.setTarget(convertView);
      anim.start();
      convertView.setTag(R.id.tag_row_animation, anim);
    }
  } else {
    if (anim != null) anim.cancel();
    convertView.setTag(R.id.tag_row_animation, null);
  }

  convertView.setTag(R.id.tag_list_person, person);  
  convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
      Person person = (Person) v.getTag(R.id.tag_list_person);
      person.toggleSelected();
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  });

  return convertView;
}

public ObjectAnimator getAnimator(View v) {
  ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0, -2, 0, 2, 0);
  a.setDuration(300);
  a.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
  return a;
}
```

As for the reason why your solution did not work: since your hashmap is saving a reference to the convertview, and the convertview is recycled every n positions (n = number of positions on screen, give or take 1 or 2), they will shake for every position % n == 0 since the previous convertview you set to shake is now going to shake for the grid cell that is n positions away since the convertview was recycled.

Comment: Verified this code works: for full activity of test check out: http://pastebin.com/GmA1XHG1